# Could not find my Intuit QBMS merchant account number

Tags: php, intuit-partner-platform

I am new to QBMS my problem is that when I try to login to quickbooks merchant service (test environment) it redirect me to:  [https://merchantcenter.intuit.com/msc/portal/addAcct] but when I click to I need a confirmation code it's asking for me to submit the merchant account number . But I am not able to find my merchant account number even though I have followed all the steps described here [https://merchantcenter.intuit.com/wapweblet/ims-mp-help/en/qbms/svc_mp_find_account_number.html] . I try to resolve it for the last 2 days but I could not.

Answer (score 0):

That is QBMS production and not a test environment. Try going through the steps here - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/030_qbms/0030_get_set_up - for testing.

Comment: I have done all these things described here . But results the same